# How can I replace std::bind with a lambda in my code

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, bind

Given the following code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct worker
{
   std::function<bool(std::string)> m_callback;

   void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)> callback)
   {
      m_callback = std::bind(callback, std::placeholders::_1); // <--- replace this with lambda
      std::cout << "worker is working..." << std::endl;
      callback("worker is complete");
   }
};


// pretty boring class - a cut down of my actual class
struct helper
{
   bool work_callback(std::string str)
   {
      std::cout << "Helper: msg from worker: " << str << std::endl;
      return false;
   }
};


int main()
{
   helper the_helper;
   worker the_worker;

   std::cout << "Main: start\n";
   the_worker.do_work([&](std::string data){ return the_helper.work_callback(data); });
   std::cout << "Main: end\n\n";
}
```

I want to replace the `m_callback = std::bind...` with a lambda. So far I have got:

`m_callback = [&](std::string data){ callback(data); };`

This gives me the error:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void worker::do_work(std::function<bool(std::basic_string<char>)>)’:
main.cpp:19:18: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::function)>’ and ‘worker::do_work(std::function)>)::’)
       m_callback = [&](std::string data){ callback(data); };
```

I am not quite sure how to move forward here. You can see my full attempt here: https://onlinegdb.com/SkaADi7u7

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish in `worker::do_work`. You have a `std::function<bool(std::string)>` parameter and want to bind an argument... But then store it into another `std::function<bool(std::string)>`. There is no need for a bind (or lambda) here - you could just do `m_callback = callback`.

Comment: Like this: `m_callback = [&](std::string const& s) { return callback(s);};` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd452cc561100e2f?

Comment: By the way, the error message you're getting is mangled because onlinegdb.com is a buggy piece of crap and doesn't properly HTML escape its messages. I recommend developing locally (or finding a different online compiler).

Comment: @melpomene The link he posted won't even open up for me...

Comment: @MaxLanghof well, this is just a silly code example I made to show the problem I am having... so please forget the "sense" of what is trying to be accomplished. I really am just trying to replace the `bind()` code.

Comment: @user1810087 Yeah, it's super slow and only loads about every third try.

Comment: @user1810087 ...ahh, damn, I forgot the return!?. Thanks :)

Comment: @melpomene I had to copy this over from my secure network so I am using this online compiler to create my examples!... do you know of a better one - I agree its aweful slow : (

Comment: @code_fodder https://godbolt.org/ for assembly inspection and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ or http://wandbox.org/ for running things.

Comment: https://ideone.com/ and https://tio.run/#cpp-gcc seem to be less awful.

Comment: Try to call `m_callback` outside `do_work` and see what happen...(i think it will be seg fault),  by `[&]` you are capturing `callback` by reference but it is local variable.

Comment: @melpomene I dislike `ideone.com` because it makes iterating on your code needlessly tedious (and wastes a ton of screen estate for ads etc.).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Agreed on the iterating, I haven't seen any ads, though.

Comment: @anyone.... why I am getting down votes. I have a minimal complete example. I have a specific question... what else?... except being too dumb? :o ... oh well : (

Comment: @code_fodder I don't know (I didn't downvote the question), but your code is far from minimal.

Comment: @melpomene - but... its like two little classes and a main()... I made every effort to make it minimal and still do somthing representative of what I am doing in my real code : )

Comment: @code_fodder Here's a minimal version: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Uj4dvBe0s5N6PG4R

Comment: @melpomene ok, that is smaller and proves are you more of a badass then me! .. but it does not really represent my code in terms of passing member functions around and what I am trying to do. I could make your example even more minimal by removing all the spaces / new-lines!. (I do like that wandbox btw). But I am trying to learn how to construct a nice question and I will take your feedback onboard with thanks : )

Comment: @code_fodder Well, your question is really just about why that one line is causing an error. Everything else is irrelevant. Ideally when you're trying to isolate a bug or error, you boil it down to a single statement or expression that makes no sense. Then you can ask a specific question about that one part (or resolve it completely: often the act of reducing a problem helps you figure it out by yourself).

Comment: @melpomene ok... that makes sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)> callback)
{
   m_callback = [&](std::string data){ callback(data); };

   std::cout << "worker is working..." << std::endl;
   callback("worker is complete");
}
```

Your lambda calls the `callback` function that you pass to it, but doesn't return the result of it, meaning it returns `void`, and you can't assign it to a `std::function<bool(std::string)>`.

Add a return in your lambda.

```
m_callback = [&](std::string data){ return callback(data); };
```

Comment: It certainly would, better still `m_callback = std::move(callback);` would work as well.

Comment: Hangon.... you are saying I don't even need the lambda....gotto try that!

Comment: @melpomene yup.. that worked! - I think I have no idea why I was using bind to start with. Please also post that as an answer and I will upvote it. But this answer does answer my specific question so thanks Kaldrr

Comment: @paler123...even better, same comment to you then I think. Although if you could explain why the move that would really help me : )

Comment: As rafix07 said, you're capturing a local variable (`callback`) by reference, which is left dangling when `do_work` returns.